# SQL Server Criar um filtro em um campo DateTime, trazendo as 24 horas anteriores (sem contar a hora atual)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Boa noite, estou com dificuldades para colocar um filtro de datas, 
Tenho uma query onde trago as informaçõs de CD, Grua e DtRegistro (datetime)
Nesta query já estou filtrando as 24 horas entre o dia atual e 24 horas antes,

```
GRU_DT_REGISTRO between GETDATE()-1 and GETDATE()
```

Neste Filtro eu tento definir que me traga a a partir da data e hora atual, as 24 horas antes, porém ele traz dados de 25 horas, ou seja 22:00 de hoje até 22 horas de ontem, 
Eu gostaria que exibisse as 24 horas anteriores sem contar com a DataHora atual, por exemplo agora são: 06/08/2017 22:15:00, então no meu filtro deverá ter datas entre 05/08/2017 22:00 & 06/08/2017 21:59:00
Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda:

Estou usando Sql Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a Função `DATEADD()` para retorna 1 dia anterior ao exato momento da execução do filtro. A função leva 3 argumentos:

1. O intervalo ex:(day, month, year e etc);
2. O número de dias ex:(nº negativos para subtração, e positivos para adição);
3. Data referencia;

Tenta desse jeito:

```
GRU_DT_REGISTRO BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Pode usar CAST para retornar só a data:

```
GRU_DT_REGISTRO BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: Valeu @LeandroAngelo nem percebi.

Answer (score 0):

Viva,

1.º é preciso tomar muito cuidado quando estamos a tratar de datas. Embora o código

```
SELECT GetDate()-1
```

entenda automaticamente que se trata de -1 dia, poderia perfeitamente considerar -1 segundo, minuto, hora, semana, ano, etc. Até por uma questão de futura leitura, o melhor é colocar de forma explícita.

Então, primeiro separe identifique a data máxima:

```
DECLARE @DFin as smalldatetime=cast(concat(cast(GetDate() as date), ' ', Left(cast(GetDate() as time),2),':00') as smalldatetime)
DECLARE @DIni as smalldatetime=DateAdd(day,-1,@DFin)

SELECT *
FROM Tabela1
WHERE DataHora>=@DIni And DataHora<@DFin
```

Note que não usei o **Between**, porque o **Beteween** inclui os valores conotados.

> Atenção: a função CONCAT com mistura de tipos de dados só funciona a
>   partir do SQL Server 2012